# Selecting multiple dates from a calendar

Tags: delphi

Is there a way to select multiple dates in a calendar component?

I want the user to fetch records from a DB based on the selected dates, not from a range of dates between two dates, but the dates the user selects on a calendar.

Would one build an array of selected dates and loop through the array, or is there a SQL way to do this?

I would like to fetch records from multiple dates that can be selected from a history table, and those specifically selected dates are not necessarily in a range but at different dates of the month, eg one date could be on the first day of the month and another on the fifteenth of the month, and so forth. I want to build a report that calculates sales done for those specific dates.

Comment: You are essentially asking 2 separate questions. How to let the user choose non-consecutive dates, and how to fetch records for non-consecutive dates. StackOverflow guidelines prefer 1 question per post. That being said, the latter is fairly easy, using an `IN` clause with a list of dates. But for the former, I'm not aware of a standard Calendar component that allows for such a selection, they usually only allow single-date or consecutive-range selection only. You might need a 3rd party calendar to accomplish what you want.

Comment: The calendar in the Raize/Konopka controls has an OnGetBoldDays that could be used to indicate selected dates by making them bold. Would need to keep track of the list of selected dates elsewhere and update that list in the OnChange or other events. The Windows 10 Calendar View component also has an OnDrawDayItem that could be used to do something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TCalendarView` control (in the Tool Palette under **Windows 10**) has the ability you are asking for. I can not check earlier than Delphi 10.1 Berlin, but there it was present.

With property `SelectionMode = smMultiple` You can select individual days and they are remembered in the `property SelectedDates[]`. Count of selected dates can be read from `property SelectedCount`.

[image]